Why Toast message not appear in react-native-root-toast?
I implemented react-native-root-toast in my expo application, I am using expo 51, please refer below code to understand the problem
const bgColor = {
    'error': {
        color: '#DA5C53',
        iconName: <WarningIcon size="5" color="error.800" alignSelf="center" mr="5"/>,
        iconColor: "error.800"
    },
    'success': {
        color: '#36AE7C',
        iconName: <CheckCircleIcon size="5" color="success.800" alignSelf="center" mr="5"/>,
        iconColor: "success.800"
    },
    'info': {
        color: '#4D96FF',
        iconName: <InfoIcon size="5" color="info.800" alignSelf="center" mr="5"/>,
        iconColor: "info.800"
    }
}
export function ShowToast({
    id,
    status,
    title,
    description
  }: toastType){

    if(description == undefined){
        description = "Some error occured"
    }
    console.log(description, "description")
    let toast = Toast.show("Some error occured", {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: bgColor[status].color ,
        delay: 2000,
        hideOnPress: true,
        opacity: 1,
        shadow: true,
        animation: true,

    })
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        Toast.hide(toast);
    }, 5000)
}

I used different toastOptions but not working, help me How to fix it?

Wrap this component in your App.js or root component.
I copied below from the guide documentation of "react-native-root-toast"
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';

// in your render function 
return (
  <RootSiblingParent>  // <- Use RootSiblingParent to wrap your root component
    <App />
  </RootSiblingParent>
);

Normally you don't need to install "react-native-root-siblings" as it comes from the toaster package. Still, if the compiler throws an error, you can install
npm install react-native-root-siblings

This is the reference
Reference

I already done it @Idrees Ahmed
``
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Root' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
<Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
</Stack.Navigator>
{/*  */}
<StatusBar backgroundColor={'#3a94e4'} hidden={false}/>



Hello @SwapnilAPawar Do you find a solution ? I have also a similar  problem

not work now ...

i'm using expo version 52,
in my case i have to wrap "<Toast" into my RootLayout in _layout.tsx:
example:
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Redirect href="/login" />
            <Stack>
              <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
            </Stack>
            <Toast />
          </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

you can adjust with you case
